# fetching friends data from google Plus for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, google-plus

I am integrating Google+ in my Windows mobile 8 application. I am able to get my login detail by following http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321291/Google-OAuth2-on-Windows-Phone. How can I can get the detail of my friends? For example: friend's id, name and image. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance. Every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ documentation is actually pretty detailed when it comes to the API.

To get a person's information, you would use:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId
```

To get a person's user ID, you could use:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=Name+of+person+to+search+for&maxResults=1
```

The above query would search for "Name of person to search for" and limit the results to 1. This is what you would use if you were expecting the result to be exactly what you entered.

Check out the full documentation at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people for more information. If you run into a problem with your code, then you should post that problem for us to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated endpoint for this. See https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list for more info.